# Advantage of AnyCancellable.store(in:) over Set<AnyCancellable>.insert(:)

Tags: swift, combine

Experimenting with Combine, I've seen the `AnyCancellable.store(in:)` method for retaining Subscribers. I've been wondering with this setup:

```
class Controller
{
  static var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
}

let label = UILabel(frame: .zero)
```

if there's an advantage over retaining a `Subscriber` with this:

```
Controller.$value
  .assign(to: \UILabel.text, on: label)
  .store(in: &cancellables)
```

over this:

```
let subscriber = Controller.$value
  .assign(to: \UILabel.text, on: label)

Controller.cancellables.insert(subscriber)
```

or if it's mainly stylistic. Both seem to work in testing.

Comment: Even though I've given an answer, I believe that this question is a matter of opinion, and as such I have voted to close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you *know* that you'll only need one reference to a `AnyCancellable`, then you can store a direct reference to that and avoid the `Set<AnyCancellable>`

Otherwise, there is no difference aside from the stylistic one.  I prefer `store(in:)` to avoid the need to use a local variable to maintain readability. (Of course, you *could* wrap the return value of your pipeline in a `Controller.cancellables.insert` but that's just downright ugly IMO.)

I would still recommend using the `store(in:)` approach so you don't need to change your implementation if you *do* end up needing to hold onto more `AnyCancellable` references.

Comment: You store it in a set - it is ok. But when and how do you clear it?